# fast static key-value mapping

Tags: java, string, performance, dictionary

I have a set of unique key-value pairs, both key and value are strings. The number of pairs is very huge and finding the value of a certain string is extremely time-critical.

The pairs are computed beforehand and are given for a certain program. So i could just write a method containing:

```
public String getValue(String key)
{
    //repeat for every pair
    if(key.equals("abc"))
    {
        return "def";
    }
}
```

but i am talking about more than 250,000 pairs and perhaps sorting them could be faster...

I am having a class that contains the `getValue()` method and can use its constructor, but has no connection to any database/file system etc. So every pair has to be defined inside the class.

Do you have any ideas that could be faster than a huge series of if-statements? Perhaps using a sorting map that gets the pairs presorted. Perhaps improve constructor-time by deserializing an already created map?

I would like your answers to contain a basic code example of your approach, I will comment answers with their corresponding time it took an a set of pairs!

Time-frame: for one constructor call and 20 calls of `getValue()` 1000 milliseconds.

Keys have a size of 256 and values have a size < 16

Comment: keys have a fixed length?

Comment: yes they have, if this makes it faster! 99% of all keys are size 256 and 1% < 256. The 1% is not critical!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is made for.  It provides `O(1)` lookup if implemented correctly, which means that as long as you have enough memory and your hash function and collision strategy are smart, it can get values for keys in constant time.  Java has multiple hash-backed data structures, from the sounds of things a `HashMap<String, String>` would do the trick for you.

You can construct it like this:

```
 Map<String, String> myHashTable = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

add values like this:

```
 myHashTable.put("abcd","value corresponding to abcd");
```

and get the value for a key like this:

```
myHashTable.get("abcd");
```

You were on the right track when you had the intuition that running through all of the keys and checking was not efficient, that would be an `O(n)` runtime approach, since you'd have to run through all `n` elements.

Comment: what would be your suggested way of initializing the map? Since map creation/insertion is also critical.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What my question in the comment above was: Would it be faster to create the map beforehand and than serialize it. Because insertion would be the bottleneck here imo...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question or exactly what you mean by "and then serialize it" but you definitely only want to create the hashtable once, not every time you have to search it or insert something into it, if that's what you're asking. Reading a quarter million values will take some time, relatively speaking, and since I/O is costly you don't want to do that any more often than you have to.

Comment: My thought was to initialize the hashmap and insert all pairs. Then serialize it. in the time-critical part, i have a String containing the serialized map. And instead of inserting all pairs in the time-critical block, i deserialize the map with all pairs already inserted.

Comment: Yes, you definitely do not want to initialize the hashtable during the time critical block; do it beforehand.